# How to hide the Dock from Mission Control in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur

How can I stop the Dock from ever appearing in macOS Big Sur?

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 9999 && killall Dock
```

Makes it practically never appear, apart from in Mission Control.

How can I get rid of the Dock from Mission Control?